# netplan bridge cannot ping local network devices

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, netplan, network-bridge

I know there are a lot of problems like mine in here, but I still cannot solve my problem.

I updated my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 and wanted to start using netplan. Unfortunately I'm not able to ping my local network devices, now. I can ping my router on 10.4.0.1, but I'm not able to ping any other device.

My netplan config looks like that:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      interfaces:
        - enp4s0
      optional: true
```

After applying I got following IPs

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:88:e4:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.4.0.11/24 brd 10.4.0.255 scope global noprefixroute enp4s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:88:e4:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.4.0.11/24 brd 10.4.0.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 85745sec preferred_lft 85745sec
    inet6 xxxx:babe:00/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6546sec preferred_lft 2946sec
    inet6 xxxx:babe::00/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6846sec preferred_lft 1446sec
    inet6 xxxx:babe00/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6846sec preferred_lft 1446sec
    inet6 xxxx:babe::00/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Routing looks like this:

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.4.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 br0
0.0.0.0         10.4.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 enp4s0
10.4.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
10.4.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 enp4s0
10.4.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 br0
10.144.158.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxdbr0
10.199.151.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
```

Is it correct that enp4s0 and br0 got the same IPv4? I think because of bridging enp4s0 should not have an ipv4..

Comment: You are correct that you should not have the ips on enp4s0.  And those are not being assigned to the interface via the current netplan config.  Does this problem persist after a reboot?  (Always the surest way to ensure your netplan config is fully current)  Do you know if you have any other services running on the system that would be running dhcp for the ethernet interface?

Comment: Yes, I rebooted and restarted the router, but the problem still exists. I also did a test and removed the bridge from the config and set both dhcp of enp4s0 to "no". But bizarrely my interface still got an ip. I also removed ifupdown and the /etc/network/interfaces file. In syslog I can see that the dhcp process is still spawned. Really don't know what to do..

Comment: I installed docker and lxc/lxd, but I don't think that they spawn the dhcp service.

Comment: OMG... I found out what was going wrong. Don't know why but after the update dhcpcd was enabled as a systemd service per default

Comment: it is normal that if you have the package installed, the systemd unit is enabled by default.    But nothing depends on dhcpd, so this shouldn't be enabled unless you explicitly install it.

Comment: I'm really sure that I didn't run something like `sudo apt install dhcpd` or `sudo service dhcpd enable`. And as I said before the update everything was working well. So I think something must have broken during the update.

Comment: it is not possible that this broke as a result of an Ubuntu upgrade because, as I said, nothing depends on the dhcpd package.  It will only be installed if you manually selected it for installation, or if you have some other, non-Ubuntu software running on your system that is installing packages on your behalf.

Comment: I checked my history and there is nothing that was installing or enabling dhcpd. But it doesn't matter. It was solved by disabling it so I'm happy now